# ngIf Async Pipe as value with only null check

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular10, rxjs-observables, async-pipe

I have an observable that I would like to create a variable with in the ngIf as well as only return false if the value is null (the observable returns a number)

I need to explicitly check for null as my observable can return 0 as a value which triggers the else block.

I have tried the following

```
*ngIf="(observable$ | async) as obs; obs !== null; esle #elseTemplate"
```

```
*ngIf="((observable$ | async) as obs) !== null; esle #elseTemplate"
```

```
*ngIf="(observable$ | async) !== null; $implicit = obs; else #elseTemplate"
// this returns the boolean
```

My current solution which doesn't seem very elegant is

```
*ngIf="(observable$ | async) !== null; esle #elseTemplate"
{{ observable$ | async }}
```

I am using Angular 10.

Comment: doesn't it works without the null checker? *ngIf="observable$ | async as obs; else elseTemplate"

Comment: my value is a number that can return 0 and therefore doesn't get displayed it goes to the elseTemplate

Comment: null is falsy. Theoretically `(observable$ | async) !== null` and `(observable$ | async)` are the same.

Comment: Ran into this exact problem. Want to show results when the value emitted is 0. This should not be this difficult... Thank you for posting this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when I deal with observables in the template like this, I find it far easier to create a single vm$ observable that's built from other observables in the component like this (note, eventually combineLatest will support dictionaries which will mean you won't have to do the map):

```
vm$ = combineLatest([
    this.observable$,
    this.observable2$
])
.pipe(
    map(([observable, observable2]) => ({
        observable,
        observable2
    }))
);
```

Then in your dom, you do an ngIf on the vm$ and you can compare the output of your observable directly.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
    <ng-container *ngIf="vm.observable !== null; else #elseTemplate">
    
    </ng-container>
    ...
</ng-container>
```

**EDIT**
For when combineLatest supports a dictionary the vm$ creation becomes simpler:

```
vm$ = combineLatest({
    observable: this.observable$,
    observable2: this.observable2$
})
```

Comment: Does this pattern have a name or do you have a link to more information? if you had n more would you do `vm$ = combineLatest([
    observable$,
   obn$
])
.pipe(
    map(([observable,obn$]) => ({
        observable,
       obn$
    }))
);`???

Comment: It's brought over from when I used to work with angularJs quite a lot. I recall seeing it on a pluralsight video and a quick google search shows others use it as well. And you're exactly right it would work like that (I've updated my answer).

Comment: Note that `combineLatest` will only start emitting once all the streams inside emit. You would have to add `startWith` to all 'sub-streams' to force emission.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I can recommend is the usage of the ngx observe directive from Nils Melhorn https://github.com/nilsmehlhorn/ngx-observe

With this directive you are allowed to define templates for next, loading and even error. The next template also is triggered if a falsy value like your zero is emitted.

```
*ngxObserve="observable$; let obs; before loadingTemplate; error errorTemplate"
```

Comment: I'd be weary of using 3rd party npm packages that are rarely used or maintained. Looking at the github for it the last real code change was 8 months ago. It's not up to date with the latest 2 versions of angular (and several minor ones).

Comment: It is just a handy directive, what regular updates do you expect? He could also copy the directives code tho.